# Setting Context for ios screenshots

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to take a screenshot of a specific part of the screen. I have set up a method to tale a shot of the whole screen, but I want a specific section.
I know I have to change this code:

```
CGSize imageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

But I tried using the CGRectMake (50,50, 400, 400) instead of [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size and it gives an error... Why?

Comment: can you paste your entire code here?

Comment: `CGSize` uses `CGSizeMake`. `CGRect` uses `CGRectMake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(50,50, 400, 400);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: actually I realized it doesn't

Comment: by doing (50,50, 2000, 400);, it takes as the width only half of the screen. it is not possible. the valuse I insert seem wrong